# What does 'to be a story' means?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Could you explain to me, please, what the expression "You are a story" means, used in the following dialogue:

A: “You mustn’t pay any attention to old Addie,” she now said to the little girl.
B: “She’s ailing today.”
A: “Will you shut your mouth?” said the woman in bed. “I am not.”
B: “You’re a story.”

Comment: You need to provide more information, like the name and author of the book.

Comment: 'A Visit of Charity” by Eudora Welty

Comment: It would be like saying: You're a poem, to someone. What are the characteristics of a story? Inventive, full of words, for example.

Comment: Thanks! Now I should try to find an equivalent in my native language. :)

Comment: This question might be closed here. Just letting you know. They might say it is "interpretation of literary writing". Good luck to you. Welty is a great writer....

Comment: Seems to equate to *You're a character.*